# Why this C++ type deduction is allowed

Tags: c++, type-deduction

I encountered some production code which made me wonder why it compiled.
I've distilled it down to the following.

I compiled it with gcc 6.4.1 and 8.1 along with a couple of other online compilers and they all report no errors.

```
struct Y
{
};

struct X
{
    using XY = Y;
};

struct VZ
{
    virtual void f( X::X::XY xy ) = 0;
};

struct Z : public VZ
{
    virtual void f( X::XY xy ) override {}
};

int main( int c, char *v[] )
{
}
```

Notice that the pure virtual is declared with what looks like an incorrect type (X::X::XY). It also make no difference how many X:: I prepend the type with, it still compiles.

I suspect that it may be a simple parser issue but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior, it's called [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). `X::X` refers to the class name `X`, and same as `X::X::X`, and so on. `X::X::XY` is same as `X::XY` here.

> In a class scope, the name of the current class is treated as if it were a public member name; this is called injected-class-name.

---

<sup>BTW: This has nothing to do with [type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction); which is usually used as another term of C++.</sup>